# Print line gets syntax error when run in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def elect():
              global elimed
              elimed = 0
              seats = int(input("\nHow many seats are available? "))
              if seats > 5:
                  print("There are only 5 candidates standing! Please start again.")
                  menu()
              global file
              file = str(input("\nEnter the file path (.txt file) : "))
              if not file.endswith(".txt"):
                  file = file + ".txt"
              if os.path.exists(file) == False:
                  print(file. "not found, Please start again")
                  menu()
              else:
                  print("Selecting file", file)
```

The 12th line keeps coming up with a syntax error, involving the " at the end. Any ideas?

Comment: Indentation Alert

Comment: Where is `menu()` defined

Comment: `print(file. "not found, Please start again")` this is illegal

Comment: As the previous comment says it's a syntax error in the print. It should be `file,` not `file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.` within `print()` use `,` instead.

Change this:

```
print(file. "not found, Please start again")
```

to this:

```
print(file, "not found, Please start again")
```

Or even better, use `format()`:

```
print("{}, not found, Please start again".format(file))
```

Answer (score 1):

The '.' in the syntax is causing this error. Should be a comma instead of dot.

> print(file, "not found, Please start again")